# TCPDF library in JOOMLA! component outputs html in PDF

Tags: joomla, components, tcpdf

I have a component in joomla that exports to PDF, the problem that i'm encountering is that the PDF exported is unreadable because the html of the Joomla! page in inserted after and before the pdf itself.

I have made a standard structure of a component and call it like

```
index.php?option=com_listado_factura&task=exportar_pdf
```

being `com_listado_factura` the name of the component and `exportar_factura` the function of the controller that exports to pdf.

I've looked everywhere and couldn't find the solution, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution was to call:

`ob_end_clean();`

before

```
$tcpdf->output();
```